# Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

Attempting to compile and debug the Android application I am working on resulted in the following errors:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_prodDebugStagingCompile'.
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/8.1.0/play-services-analytics-8.1.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/8.1.0/play-services-analytics-8.1.0.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/8.1.0/play-services-analytics-8.1.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/8.1.0/play-services-analytics-8.1.0.jar
 ...
```

Are these sources down or expired?

Comment: update android sdk ... "Extras=>Google repository" as this library is used to be taken from local repo

Comment: @Selvin Where is this located? "Extras=>Google repository"

Comment: http://selvin.pl/howtousegoogle667.png

Comment: Open the Android Studio SDK manager, make sure all of your build tools are up to date. Then make sure your Google Play Services and Google Repository packages are up to date. In the Android Studio sdk manager, you'll find these under the "SDK Tools" tab. If you are using the standalone sdk manager, you would scroll down to the "Extras" section at the bottom and update them there.

Comment: @drschultz Thank you for your assistance. Got it all resolved now, thank you!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Open the Android Studio SDK manager, make sure all of your build tools are up to date. Then make sure your Google Play Services and Google Repository packages are up to date. In the Android Studio sdk manager, you'll find these under the "SDK Tools" tab. If you are using the standalone sdk manager, you would scroll down to the "Extras" section at the bottom and update them there.

Comment: Minimum SDK versions: https://github.com/googleads/google-media-framework-android (under Requirements > Development)