# i integrated my app with google play services but in old versions before 5.X it crashes after updating google play service to 8.4.0

Tags: android, google-play-services

the app launches successfully in any version after 5.X but in old versions 4.X it crashes and give me this error                                          :

```
       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
```

this is builde.gradle

```
          apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

            android {
            compileSdkVersion 23
              buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
                defaultConfig {
             applicationId "com.appsinnovate.hanorder"
       //        manifestPlaceholders =  
            [manifestApplicationId:"${applicationId}"]
              manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          :  
                       "${applicationId}",
                                               onesignal_app_id               
                    : "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                            onesignal_google_project_number:"xxxxxxxxx"]
                          minSdkVersion 15
                        targetSdkVersion 22
                         versionCode 1
                         versionName "1.0"
                       multiDexEnabled true
                           }
                     buildTypes {
                          release {
         minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   
           'proguard-rules.pro'
              }
                    }
           productFlavors {
                  }
             useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
                 dexOptions {
              incremental true
              javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
                }
                }


               repositories {
              mavenCentral()
               }

               dependencies {
            compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

           compile project(':facebook')

           compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
           compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
           compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
           compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
          compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
          compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:1.+@aar'
          compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
          compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
          compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
          compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
           compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
          compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

           }
         apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle (application)

```
         buildscript {
           repositories {
               jcenter()
                     }
                   dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
                classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'

                   }
                    }

               allprojects {
                   repositories {
                jcenter()
                  }
                   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem by removing

```
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

because it need to use multiDexing because size exceeds 65K

so i removed from builde.gradle

```
        dexOptions {
          incremental true
          javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
            }

        ......
                   multiDexEnabled true
        ......
                   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

and i used libraries that i need

```
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get this if you have not added the google play services library to your project correctly. Make sure you carefully follow the instructions at https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup to add the library to your project. Then make sure you have all of your build tools and google repository packages up to date, as outline in my answer here: [Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32909421/could-not-find-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-analytics8-1-0/32956275#32956275)

Once you update all of this, it should work. I also noticed your google play package looks out of date. You have version 2.0.0. Current version should be `8.4.0` The line in your gradle should read `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`

Also, it looks like you have this in your Project gradle file. It should go in your MODULE gradle file instead.

**UPDATE**

---

You should change your gradle version to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'` I missed this on my original read through, but this should solve your issue.

Comment: i followed google documentation and  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'
 is up todate iam sure @NoChinDeluxe

Comment: Make sure you put the play services declaration in your MODULE gradle file. It looks like you have it in your project gradle file. It should be in your module gradle file, under dependencies, using the "compile" keyword like this `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`

Comment: i added it in module but give me that Error:(10, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
 i think i should not put it module @ NoChinDeluxe

Comment: That's because you have to REMOVE it from your project gradle, and add it ONLY to the module gradle. In other words, keep the compile statement in your module gradle, and delete the `classpath` statement for google play in your project gradle. You also should not need `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in there either.

Comment: in app module don't accept to add compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' , and it is works on 5.x versions

Comment: Hmmm ok one other thing you can try. Try changing this line `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'` to this `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'` (keep everything else you originally had the same)

Comment: sorry it refused to build after i changed it to 2.0.0 :( :( @NoChinDeluxe

Comment: Did you make sure it had the `alpha6` on the end? If that doesn't work then I'm out of ideas. That's about all I know about this issue haha. Gradle is such a headache sometimes :(