# Problems with google api's

Tags: android, google-app-engine

When compiling, I am getting this error:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

But, when removing the line:
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'

I am getting the following errors:
Error:(41, 42) error: package com.google.android.gms.appindexing does not exist
Error:(42, 42) error: package com.google.android.gms.appindexing does not exist

Tried to delete the other line:
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
I am getting the following errors:
Error:(41, 42) error: cannot find symbol class Action
Error:(162, 67) error: cannot find symbol variable API

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to compile two separate versions of the library. Just use the latest one. You might also want to make sure all of your build tools and repository packages are up to date. See my answer here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32909421/could-not-find-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-analytics8-1-0/32956275#32956275

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours I found the solution.
I removed the:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
```

and improted the failed symbols 'Action' and 'variable API' from:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
```

And this solved my problems.